# Использование удаленной функции

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Пытаюсь разобраться в умных указателях (unique_ptr), но до конца не понимаю как это все работает.
Есть функция которая задает и использует стратегию (Simple, Medium или Strong).
Я создаю умный указатель и инициализирую его стратегией, которая мне нужна.

```
string generate_password(string _strat, int _lenght_pass, string _alphabet) {

    unique_ptr <Strategy> _strateg ;    
    PasswordGenerator _pwdgen;
    if (_strat == "simple") {
        _strateg = make_unique <Simple>();
    } else
    if (_strat == "medium") {
        _strateg = make_unique <Medium>();
    } else
    if (_strat == "strong") {
        _strateg = make_unique <Strong>();
    }
    if (_strateg) {
        _pwdgen.setStrategy(_strateg);
        string retval =  _pwdgen.useStrategy(_lenght_pass, _alphabet);
        //delete _strateg;
        return retval;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Но при использвонии setStrategy появляется ошибка use of deleted function.
[image: ERROR]

Это функция setStrategy

```
void PasswordGenerator:: setStrategy(std::unique_ptr <Strategy> o)
{
    operation = o;
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unique_ptr` потому так и называется, что он уникален - только один, копировать его нельзя. А вы в вызове `setStrategy(std::unique_ptr <Strategy> o)` именно это и пытаетесь делать...

Comment: а как тогда его можно передать в функцию?

Comment: @Arcanecliff `_pwdgen.setStrategy(std::move(_strateg));`. Плюс в самой функции присваивание переписать так: `operation = std::move(o);`.

Comment: А в чем разница если я буду принимать ссылку на unique_ptr, вот так: 


`void PasswordGenerator:: setStrategy(std::unique_ptr <Strategy>& o)
{
    operation = move(o);
}`


есть разница, или так тоже будет верно?

Comment: @Arcanecliff Принимать lvalue ссылку, а потом перемещать из нее - моветон, имхо. Когда я передаю объект в функцию, я не ожидаю, что она из него переместит. Уж лучше rvalue ссылку. Тогда вызывать функцию все равно нужно будет с `std::move`, но будет на одно перемещение меньше.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это на какое? Внутри функции все равно надо мувить.

Comment: @bipll Я имею в виду, по сравнению с передачей по значению.